# Upload Multiple Assets to an Entity

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

On documentation it is said that `Only 1 asset can be attached to an entity.` Is there any way to attach multiple images to an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. You can work around the limitation by using [folders](http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/folders-organizing-assets), and connecting them to a user or other entity:

> Linking a folder to an asset
>
> In order to access the asset for the image in the folder, you need to link the folder to the asset. You can do that by issuing a POST request in the following format:
>
> ```
> POST /{org-uuid}/{app-uuid}/folders/{folder-uuid}/assets/{assets_id}
> ```
>
> where `{folder-uuid}` is the UUID of the folder, and `{assets-uuid}` is the UUID of the assets entity.
>
> Here’s how you could link the folder and the asset you created for the my-image.jpg image:
>
> ```
> POST https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/folders/6640a601-2ac6-11e2-92c3-02e81ae640dc/assets/9501cda1-2d21-11e2-b4c6-02e81ac5a17b
> ```